Let's get critical: Jun 2013 Site Self-Evaluation
We all love Quantitative Finance Stack Exchange, but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.
The Site Self-Evaluation review queue is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.
Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? Post an answer below to share your thoughts and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Final Results

What is the difference between convertible bond and bond with warrant?
Net Score: 2 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

Transformation to reduce standard deviation without changing median
Net Score: 0 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)

Testing Significance of Correlation
Net Score: -1 (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)

Non-arbitrage theory and existence of a risk premium
Net Score: 4 (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

Iterating through every path of a Trinomial Tree
Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

How to download risk free rate?
Net Score: -3 (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 3)

In Black-Scholes, why is $\log{\frac{S_{t+\triangle t}}{S_t}} \sim \phi{((\mu - \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)\triangle t, \sigma^2 \triangle t)}$?
Net Score: 4 (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

Bond curve extrapolation
Net Score: -1 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 3)

Is vega of Black-Scholes European type option always positive?
Net Score: 3 (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

Analyze raw tick data
Net Score: 0 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)



The results are in. The two highest-rated questions are:

Non-arbitrage theory and existence of a risk premium
In Black-Scholes, why is $\log{\frac{S_{t+\triangle t}}{S_t}} \sim \phi{((\mu - \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)\triangle t, \sigma^2 \triangle t)}$?

The lowest-rated question is:

How to download risk free rate?

Pretty similar to last time, actually.
